# html5 video and bootstrap modal window

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, video, bootstrap-modal

I know this has been asked before, but for whatever reason I can't resolve my issue with the answers. Using html5 video in a bootstrap modal window, on window close video still plays. Tried the following and can't seem to get it to work.

```
$("#myModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $("#myModal video").attr("src", $("#myModal video").attr("src"));
});
```

I replaced #myModal with #openVideo which is the id to open the modal window.

This is the test link for modal: http://beckerinsurancegroup.com/test/

It's a WP site, so perhaps the above code needs tweaking to accommodate, just not sure what needs to be done. Also, it's an mp4 video housed on the client's server, not a youtube or vimeo... so no iframe is being use.

I'll disclaim this by saying I'm not fluent in JS, just looking for a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not so sure that the handler for `hidden.bs.modal` is being called; however, adding this to your page will work:

```
$('a.close').click(function(){
  var video = $(this).siblings('video').get(0); 
  video.pause();
});
```

It works by adding a click handler to the "close" button on the dialog. Upon clicking on the close button, a reference to the `video` tag is obtained and the `pause();` method is called. It works. I already tested it.

Comment: Holy crap... THANK YOU so much!!! Works like a charm. Thank you to the others as well for trying to point me in the right direction.